# Check and cast error in Omnet++ TSN. Unable to transmit UDP packets

Tags: omnet++, inet

I am trying to send a UDP packet from Omnett ++ TSN Device to a standard Host through a TSN switch that is connected to a Router.
However, I get the following check_and_cast error:-

```
check_and_cast(): Cannot cast(inet::physicallayer::signal*)app[0]-0 to type 'inet::physicallayer::EthernetSignalBase *' in module (inet::EthernetMac) of router.eth[0].mac
```

My omnetpp.ini udp app setup is as follows.

```
extends = omnetpptsnnetworksample

#Source application
*.tsnDevice1.numApps = 1
*.tsnDevice1.app[0].typename = "UdpSourceApp"
*.tsnDevice1.app[0].source.packetLength = 10B
*.tsnDevice1.app[0].source.productionInterval = 1ms
*.tsnDevice1.app[0].io.destAddress = "ue[0]"
*.tsnDevice1.app[0].io.destPort = 1000
*.tsnDevice1.app[0].source.clockModule = "^.^.clock"

#Sink application
*.standardHost[*].numApps = 1
*.standardHost[*].app[*].typename = "UdpSinkApp"
*.standardHost[*].app[*].io.localPort = 1000
```

Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TsnDevice` and `TsnSwitch` have `LayeredEthernetInterface` by default, but `StandardHost` has `EthernetInterface`. The two interfaces are not compatible (not sure if they should be or not). So by setting standardHost's ethernet interface type to `LayeredEthernetInterface`, it should work:

```
*.standardHost[*].eth[*].typename = "LayeredEthernetInterface"
```